# F# why does string conversion fail with underscores

Tags: parsing, f#

Is there any particular reason why piping to int works here but the system convert doesn't? Which method should be used?

`printfn "%i" ("1_2" |> int)`
`printfn "%i" (System.Int32.Parse("1_2"))`

I am using .NET core 2.2

It looks like the first method calls

`FSharp.Core.dll!Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.ParseInt32(string s)`

and the second calls

`System.Private.CoreLib.dll!int.Parse(string s)`

---

So if anyone is curious, I looked at the difference. the .NET core dll doesnt strip underscores

System.Private.CoreLib.dll uses

```
    private static unsafe void StringToNumber(ReadOnlySpan<char> str, NumberStyles options, ref NumberBuffer number, NumberFormatInfo info, bool parseDecimal)
    {
        Debug.Assert(info != null);
        fixed (char* stringPointer = &MemoryMarshal.GetReference(str))
        {
            char* p = stringPointer;
            if (!ParseNumber(ref p, p + str.Length, options, ref number, info, parseDecimal)
                || (p - stringPointer < str.Length && !TrailingZeros(str, (int)(p - stringPointer))))
            {
                throw new FormatException(SR.Format_InvalidString);
            }
        }
    }
```

And FSharp.Core.dll uses

```
        let ParseInt32 (s:string) = 
        if System.Object.ReferenceEquals(s,null) then
            raise( new System.ArgumentNullException("s") )
        let s = removeUnderscores (s.Trim())
        let l = s.Length 
        let mutable p = 0 
        let sign = getSign32 s &p l 
        let specifier = get0OXB s &p l 
        if p >= l then formatError() else
        match Char.ToLowerInvariant(specifier) with 
        | 'x' -> sign * (int32OfUInt32 (Convert.ToUInt32(UInt64.Parse(s.Substring(p), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))))
        | 'b' -> sign * (int32OfUInt32 (Convert.ToUInt32(parseBinaryUInt64 (s.Substring(p)))))
        | 'o' -> sign * (int32OfUInt32 (Convert.ToUInt32(parseOctalUInt64  (s.Substring(p)))))
        | _ -> Int32.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: The second way throws System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
This is .NET Core 2.2

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect here. The behave differently because they're different functions with different implementations. The first one removes underscores before parsing the number, the other one does not.

Comment: Perhaps your real question is why there are several different string parsing functions in F#? To that question the answer is probably because F# mixes different traditions, the .NET tradition where number parsing is expected to work one way, and the ML tradition where number parsing is expected to work a different way.

Comment: I see, I guess that makes sense. So when I reference System now I know I hit the .net core dll which can have different opinions than hitting fsharp.core.dll

Comment: I think to find the reason for the stripping the underscores you have to ask the source: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp by creating an issue. If I let myself speculate I suppose it's to support 1000 separators like so: `1_000_000` which is somehwat easier to read than `1000000` (the source: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L2266)

Answer (score 1):

As others said two different implementations of parsing an integer is used and doesn't necessarily produce the same result. However, one might wonder *why* F# allows `1_2` as a valid int?

I browsed the history of the source code and found that it was implemented in this commit: [implement Underscore Literals](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/commit/2329fc9209)

It was made to support literals in F# like this:

```
let x = 1_000_000
let y = 1000000

x = y // true
```

x and y is equal but `1_000_000` is thanks to the underscores somewhat easier to read as 1 million.

Because how it was implemented it also leaked into runtime as now `int "1_000_000"` parse successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case `("1_2" |> int)` you are using `int` which is an F# primitive.

In the second case `(System.Int32.Parse("1_2"))` you are using `System.Int32` which is a .NET CLR and not specifically an F# type.

The two use different rules for parsing integers as you discovered in the implementations.